# Selinux blocking the module. Is seboolean "nis_enabled" secure enough?

Tags: linux, selinux, victoriametrics

I have recently configured alerting system using vmalert module (Victoriametrics product). On my system there is an enforcing SELinux policy, which shall remain so. When trying to run vmalert, it got blocked by SELinux.

It happened until I grep the contents of audit.log and feed it to audit2allow to create a policy. In addition, I can ensure it is working by enabling "nis boolean" in Selinux. However, I strongly believe there is a better way to allow it running. Any assistance in this regard is appreciated. Below is the snippet of policy that is proposed to be loaded into Selinux:

```
    module vmalert 1.0;

    require {
    type init_t;
    type unreserved_port_t;
    type http_port_t;
    class tcp_socket name_connect;
    }

    #============= init_t ==============

    #!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'nis_enabled'
    allow init_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;

    #!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'nis_enabled'
    allow init_t unreserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
```

Comment: Did you use https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/victoriametrics-lts-rpm ?

Comment: No, I retrieved it from https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/releases/ - version 1.87.0

Comment: Would you mind to send a PR to https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/victoriametrics-lts-rpm ?

Comment: @DenysHolius Sorry for late call, after another deploy this issue seemed to have not been repeated. I tried to reproduce it on VM using my ansible-playbook, by also making sure none of the audit2allow policies and booleans have been loaded beforehand and it looks like working. If anything comes up, I'll send a PR. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can allow just what is blocked (TCP connections to http ports and unreserved ports) with:

```
cat << EOF > vmalert.te
module vmalert 1.0;

require {
type init_t;
type unreserved_port_t;
type http_port_t;
class tcp_socket name_connect;
}

#============= init_t ==============

allow init_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow init_t unreserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
EOF
checkmodule -M -m -o vmalert.mod vmalert.te
semodule_package -o vmalert.pp -m vmalert.mod
semodule -i vmalert.pp
```

Comment: This is basically the same step as if you use audit2allow to create a custom policy. However, this one didn't work, since it was still blocking vmalert with "connection refused to port 8428". My guess there is a glitch inside the module, but thanks for an option!

Comment: There is no new denials showing with `audit2allow -a` when the connection to port 8428 is refused?

Comment: The output for audit2allow -a when the connection to 8428 port is refused is below: #============= init_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow init_t unreserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;

Comment: I don't know for sure then. You have no denials, although it still doesn't work, but with the boolean it works. It might be a denial in dontaudit mode, or something else I'm not awre of. I have nothing best than the boolean to advice right now then, sorry.